# How to get sum of pivot column as saprate column in SQL

Tags: sql

When i try to get sum of three columns as Total it gives null when one of column is null in Recieved,Claim or Issue

```
SELECT YarnId,
Recieve,
Issued,
Claim,
Total=Recieve+Issued
FROM
(
SELECT YarnId,Status,Bags
FROM Yarn_IssueRecieve
) as PivotData

Pivot
(
SUM(bags) for Status in (Recieve,Issued,Damage,Claim)
) as Pivoting
```

Following is the output

[image]

Comment: And what's wrong with null ? It shows exactly how your data is compiled. Showing 0 instead may mask the problems of data completeness.

Comment: Please tag appropriate database name.

Answer (score 0):

use `COALESCE`

```
Total= COALESCE (Recieve,0) + COALESCE (Issued,0)
```

and

```
SUM( COALESCE (bags,0) )
```

Comment: remember accept the answer with the green tick if solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ISNULL`

```
SELECT YarnId,
Recieve,
Issued,
Claim,
Total=ISNULL(Recieve,0)+ISNULL(Issued,0)
FROM
(
SELECT YarnId,Status,Bags
FROM Yarn_IssueRecieve
) as PivotData

Pivot
(
SUM(bags) for Status in (Recieve,Issued,Damage,Claim)
) as Pivoting
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySql or MSSQL Server, if you add any number with NULL, the result is NULL. For example-

```
SELECT 10 + NULL
--Result is NULL
```

As a result, you have handle NULL in your query to overcome the situation you are facing. You can use COALESCE for your purpose and the script should be as below-

```
Total=COALESCE(Recieve,0)+COALESCE(Issued,0)
```